# id_generator in python to print 10 id numbers

Tags: python

I built an iterator class that prints 10 several valid IDs

- The condition of stopping the iterator is 10 and so after 10 iterations the print stops
- The iterator works great, stops when needed, prints 10 valid IDs.

I want to incorporate in the code also a **generator** that will perform the same actions as the iterator, but for some reason it does not work well

- A generator function called `id_generator` that behaves similar to the IDIterator iterator.
- The generator function receives as an ID number parameter. Whenever it is asked to generate a value, it generates the next valid ID number in the range (up to 999999999)

Suggestions for solution?

https://www.codepile.net/pile/rMJgoOwq  THE  CODE  IS  HERE

```
from functools import reduce

class Identity:
    def __init__(self, identity, iterations):
        self.minimum = 0
        self.maximum = 1000000000
        self.identity = identity if type(identity) is int and identity >= self.minimum and identity <= self.maximum else 123456780
        self.iterations = iterations if type(iterations) is int and iterations >= self.minimum else 10

    def __iter__(self):
        self.last = min(self.maximum, self.identity + self.iterations * 10)
        return self

    def __next__(self):       
        if self.identity == self.last:
            raise StopIteration

        identity = (str(self.identity + self.digit() - self.identity % 10)).zfill(9)
        self.identity += 10
        return identity

    def digit(self):
        identity = str(self.identity)[:-1]
        return (10 - (reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, list(map(int, identity[0 : -1 : 2]))) + reduce(lambda a, b: a + (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9)[b], list(map(int, '0' + identity[1 : : 2])))) % 10) % 10


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for identity in Identity(121466780,10):
        print(identity)
```

Comment: What code have you written to make your generator function?

Comment: I tried to integrate the the  same digit function as there is an iterator (which checks whether a valid ID number or not) and then implement it on YIELD

Answer (score 0):

This code that you have is almost what you need:

```
for identity in Identity(121466780, 10):
    print(identity)
```

Just wrap it in a function:

```
def id_generator(identity, iterations):
    for identity in Identity(identity, iterations):
        print(identity)
```

Turn the `print` into `yield`:

```
def id_generator(identity, iterations):
    for identity in Identity(identity, iterations):
        yield identity
```

Then call it in a suitable manner:

```
for identity in id_generator(121466780, 10):
    print(identity)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I just didn't think in that direction ..I'll keep going, you can close the reference